# Why Error urllib.error.ContentTooShortError:

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

## I get this error while retrieving the program I wrote with kivy.
I have to use vpn

```
 Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r19c-linux-x86_64.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mm/kivyenv/bin/buildozer", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/mm/kivyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/mm/kivyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1047, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/home/mm/kivyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 92, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/home/mm/kivyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 102, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
  File "/home/mm/kivyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 169, in prepare_for_build
    self.target.install_platform()
  File "/home/mm/kivyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 665, in install_platform
    self._install_android_ndk()
  File "/home/mm/kivyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 455, in _install_android_ndk
    self.buildozer.download(url,
  File "/home/mm/kivyenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 677, in download
    urlretrieve(url, filename, report_hook)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1866, in retrieve
    raise ContentTooShortError(
urllib.error.ContentTooShortError: <urlopen error retrieval incomplete: got only 261037633 out of 823376982 bytes>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [urllib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html):
exception urllib.error.ContentTooShortError(msg, content)

This exception is raised when the urlretrieve() function detects that the amount of the downloaded data is less than the expected amount (given by the Content-Length header). The content attribute stores the downloaded (and supposedly truncated) data.

In practice, it's likely that the VPN terminated the socket. You may need to implement retry/resume capability in your program.